# Comparing three lists and print out set where variables match two lists but not the third

Tags: list, for-loop, set

I am trying to build a script the compares three lists 'alice', 'bob and 'silversted' which returns a set of all the same items in the lists 'alice' and 'Silvester', but the those some items do not occur in the list named 'bob':

This is my code:

```
alice = ['II', 'IV', 'II', 'XIX', 'XV', 'IV', 'II']

bob = ['IV', 'III', 'II', 'XX', 'II', 'XX']

silvester = ['XVIII', 'XIX', 'III', 'I', 'III', 'XVIII']

meet =[]

def love_meet(bob, alice):
    return (set(alice) & set(bob))
    
print(love_meet(bob, alice))

def affair_meet(bob, alice, silvester):
    for i in alice:
        for y in silvester:
            for x in bob:
                if i == y and i != x:
                    meet.append(i)
                    return (set(meet))

print(affair_meet(bob, alice, silvester)) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    assert love_meet(
        ["IV", "III", "II", "XX", "II", "XX"],
        ["II", "IV", "II", "XIX", "XV", "IV", "II"],
    ) == {"II", "IV"}

    assert affair_meet(
        ["IV", "III", "II", "XX", "II", "XX"],
        ["II", "IV", "II", "XIX", "XV", "IV", "II"],
        ["XVIII", "XIX", "III", "I", "III", "XVIII"],
    ) == {"XIX"}
```

While the output works in an online complier I am getting a message from the exercise website I am using (Hackinscience.org) saying:

> From affair_meet, I expected a set, you gave a <class 'NoneType'>

The output looks like a set, so I'm unsure what is happening here.

Also is there a better way to code this than I have so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use set methods `.intersection` and `.difference` instead of the for-loops. For example:

```py
alice = ["II", "IV", "II", "XIX", "XV", "IV", "II"]
bob = ["IV", "III", "II", "XX", "II", "XX"]
silvester = ["XVIII", "XIX", "III", "I", "III", "XVIII"]


def affair_meet(bob, alice, silvester):
    return set(alice).intersection(silvester).difference(bob)


assert (
    affair_meet(
        ["IV", "III", "II", "XX", "II", "XX"],
        ["II", "IV", "II", "XIX", "XV", "IV", "II"],
        ["XVIII", "XIX", "III", "I", "III", "XVIII"],
    )
    == {"XIX"}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ur program seems ok. Ur functions r not returning none type. I have checked that using type func. Anyways, I have tried to simplify ur code.

```
alice = ['II', 'IV', 'II', 'XIX', 'XV', 'IV', 'II']

bob = ['IV', 'III', 'II', 'XX', 'II', 'XX']

silvester = ['XVIII', 'XIX', 'III', 'I', 'III', 'XVIII']

meet =set()

def love_meet(bob, alice):
    return set(alice) & set(bob)
    
print(love_meet(bob, alice))

def affair_meet(bob, alice, silvester):
    global meet
    #meet = set() #this depends on need
    for i in set(alice) & set(silvester):
        if i not in bob:
            meet.add(i)
    return meet

print(affair_meet(bob, alice, silvester))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    assert love_meet(
        ["IV", "III", "II", "XX", "II", "XX"],
        ["II", "IV", "II", "XIX", "XV", "IV", "II"],
    ) == {"II", "IV"}

    assert affair_meet(
        ["IV", "III", "II", "XX", "II", "XX"],
        ["II", "IV", "II", "XIX", "XV", "IV", "II"],
        ["XVIII", "XIX", "III", "I", "III", "XVIII"],
    ) == {"XIX"}
```